# I want datareader to read data from a column in database which is varchar and the read result to be stored in string variable

Tags: sqldatareader, datareader

I want datareader to read data from a column in database which is varchar and the read result to be stored in string variable but it generates an indexoutofrange exception...Basically I want a validation so that if the user enters a booking time which is already in the database then program should generate an error message. Also an error should be generated if entered value is inside the booked time duration. Like if a booking is there on 12/12/2011 at 4:00 pm and the duration is 2 hours then the program should not allow any booking till 6:00 pm unless a booking is for some other game or for some other courtno (in case of badminton, squash, lawn tennis etc)

I'm trying the following code for this:

Dim str2 As String  ' defines string variable for taking select query

```
    str2 = "select booking_date, booking_time, booking_duration, poolno, courtno, tableno from Bookings"

    Dim a, b As Date
    Dim c As Date
    Dim d, f, g, l As String

    Dim dur As Integer

    Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand(str2, con)
    con.Open()

    Dim bookchk As SqlDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader
    While bookchk.Read()
        a = bookchk("booking_date")
        b = bookchk("booking_time")
        c = b.ToLongTimeString
        dur = bookchk("booking_duration")

        l = bookchk("game") 'exception is generated here


        If CmboGame.SelectedItem = "Swimming" Then
            If bookchk("poolno") IsNot System.DBNull.Value Then
                d = bookchk("poolno")

            End If

        Else : d = ""

        End If

        If CmboGame.SelectedItem = "Table Tennis" Then
            If bookchk("tableno") IsNot System.DBNull.Value Then
                f = bookchk("tableno")

            End If
        Else : f = ""
        End If
        If CmboGame.SelectedItem IsNot "Table Tennis" And CmboGame.SelectedItem IsNot "Swimming" Then
            If bookchk("courtno") IsNot System.DBNull.Value Then
                g = bookchk("courtno")

            End If
        Else : g = ""
        End If
        If TxtBookDate.Text = a And TxtBookTime.Text = c And TxtPoolNo.Text = d And TxtCrtNo.Text = g And TxtTblNo.Text = f And CmboGame.SelectedItem = l Then
            MessageBox.Show("The date and time you have entered has already been booked" & vbCrLf & "Try Again!", "Bookings Overlapped", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
            Exit Sub

        End If


        Dim time, h, i, j, n As DateTime
        n = c.AddHours(dur)
        time = TxtBookTime.Text
        h = time.AddHours(TxtBookDur.Text)
        i = time.ToLongTimeString
        j = h.ToLongTimeString


        If TxtBookDate.Text = a And TxtPoolNo.Text = d And TxtCrtNo.Text = g And TxtTblNo.Text = f And CmboGame.SelectedIndex = l And i > c And i <= n Or j > n Then
            MessageBox.Show("The date and time you have entered has already been booked" & vbCrLf & "Try Again!", "Bookings Overlapped", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)

            Exit Sub

        End If


    End While
    bookchk.Close()
    con.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL statement:

```
str2 = "select booking_date, booking_time, booking_duration, poolno, courtno, tableno from Bookings"
```

You're not selecting a column called "game", so obviously you can't reference this in your datareader. Add the "game" column to the SQL statement, assuming it exists, this problem will disappear. You might have other problems of course.

Comment: Thanks...Just forgot to change the query as I made changes in the code..Thanks alot :-)

Comment: Can anyone still help about the logic that i have mentioned for avoiding overlapped bookings....keeping time, date same if i try to book some different courtno/poolno/tblno or when i try it for different game it still generates an error message

Comment: I'm not sure asking multiple questions within the same question is a good idea - you've also provided no detail of what the problem is, so it's very difficult for anybody to provide advice.